# How to check that user does not enter decimal in C

Tags: c

I have to wrire a programm that scans numbers from 1 to 5 and shows a quote that correspond to the number.
If user enters decimals, or >5 there should be error.
My program does not work in a right way, if user enters for example 5.5 programm displays quote that corresponds to 5 but need to be an error. Programm is written in Visual Studio Code in C.

There are stranges quotes, I know :)

Thank you!

THere is an exampe:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv []){

    int x;
    float y;

    printf ("ml' nob:\n");
    scanf("%f", &y);

    x = (int)y;

    if ((y - x) == 0 && x>=1 || x<=5){
        if (x==1){
            printf ("Qapla\'\n"
            "noH QapmeH wo\' Qaw\'lu\'chugh yay chavbe\'lu\' \'ej wo\' choqmeH may\' DoHlu\'chugh lujbe\'lu\'.\n");
        }
        else if (x==2){
            printf("Qapla\'\n"
            "Qu\' buSHa\'chugh SuvwI\', batlhHa\' vangchugh, qoj matlhHa\'chugh, pagh ghaH SuvwI\'\'e\'.\n");
        }
        else if (x==3){
            printf("Qapla\'\n"
            "qaStaHvIS wa\' ram loS SaD Hugh SIjlaH qetbogh loD.\n");
        }
        else if (x==4){
            printf("Qapla\'\n"
            "Ha\'DIbaH DaSop \'e\' DaHechbe\'chugh yIHoHQo\'.\n");
        }
        else if (x==5){
            printf("Qapla\'\n"
            "leghlaHchu\'be\'chugh mIn lo\'laHbe\' taj jej.\n");
        }

    }
    else {
        printf ("luj");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you intend with `y - x == 0`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the condition `(y - x) == 0 && x>=1 || x<=5`, which is evaluated as `((y - x) == 0 && x>=1) || x<=5`.

Since `x<=5` is true, then the whole condition is true.

The reason for this is that the [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) of the logical and operator `&&` is higher than logical or operator `||`.

You need to explicitly add parentheses around the range-check: `(y - x) == 0 && (x>=1 || x<=5)`.

---

Actually, that range-check is flawed as well, as it will allow values larger than `5` (then `x>=1` will make it all true) or values less than or equal to zero (because then `x<=5` will be true). If either of the sides of the logical or operator `||` is true, then the whole condition is true.

You need to use `&&` here too: `x>=1 && x<=5`.

If you fix this then you don't need the extra parentheses, and `(y - x) == 0 && x>=1 && x<=5` will work fine.

Comment: Tnahk you for the link and explanation! I will try.

Answer (score 0):

Start with `fgets`. That will save you from problems with newline characters. Remember to check for errors.

```
#define SIZE 200
char buf[SIZE];
if (!fgets(buf, SIZE, stdin)) { 
    /* Something went wrong during reading */ 
}
```

An extra check could be to see if the input is too long to fit, but I'll skip that. Then we read the float.

```
if(sscanf(buf, "%f", &y) != 1) { 
    /* Something went wrong */ 
}
```

Now `y` have been assigned a float number. So how do we check if the *user entered decimals*? This question is very different from what you are trying to check. What you're trying to do can fail for several reasons. Rounding errors is one of them. So we can do something like this.

```
size_t len = strlen(buf);
for(size_t i=0; i<len; i++) {
    if(buf[i] == '.') { 
        /* The user entered a decimal point */ 
    }
}
```

Of course, you will have to replace the comments with appropriate error handling.

Your code (when corrected, for instance by Some programmer dude's answer) will fail for the input `1.0000001` for instance.